# Obter informações do $_SERVER do usuário via socket

Tags: php, websocket

Veja, estou usando `new WebSocket` para desenvolver minhas aplicações e preciso de alguma forma ter acesso a estas variáveis da conexão que estou recebendo através do sockets sobre PHP, existe forma para isso ou não é possível?

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] 
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] 
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

para o desenvolvimento do servidor uso como base esta classe:

https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php

Comment: Não há o que se desculpar, estamos todos aqui para aprender :) ... Faz um favor apaga os comentários antigos. +1 para pergunta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no aguardo :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trazer o IP e os dados será necessário trocar a função [`socket_recv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php) pela função [`socket_recvfrom`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php)

> Sobre a minha [**resposta anterior**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/60061/3), ignore-a, aquela parte que eu disse que no "CLI não funciona", eu estava totalmente enganado :)

Para pegar os dados é necessário editar o arquivo `class.PHPWebSocket.php` nas linhas 136 e 143:

```
...
foreach ($changed as $clientID => $socket) {
    if ($clientID != 0) {
        // client socket changed
        $buffer = '';
        $bytes = @socket_recvfrom($socket, $buffer, 4096, 0, $ipaddress, $port);/*$bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 4096, 0);*/

        if ($bytes === false) {
            // error on recv, remove client socket (will check to send close frame)
            $this->wsSendClientClose($clientID, self::WS_STATUS_PROTOCOL_ERROR);
        }
        elseif ($bytes > 0) {
            echo $buffer, PHP_EOL;
            echo 'IP: ', $ipaddress, ' e porta ', $port, PHP_EOL;
            echo '-------------------------', PHP_EOL;

            // process handshake or frame(s) 
            if (!$this->wsProcessClient($clientID, $buffer, $bytes)) {
...
```

Então no terminal ou CMD execute o `server.php`:

```
php5 ./server.php
```

Em seguida abra o arquivo `index.html` (pelo protocolo file também funciona) em dois navegadores diferentes, Firefox e Opera por exemplo e mande uma mensagem de cada um dos navegadores.

Olhe na tela do terminal/cmd e notará que recebeu dois buffers com este:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9300
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.51
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: MU8AuFEjzsMrwFh/R2gmZA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

IP: 0.0.0.0 e porta 0
-------------------------
2015-04-25 04:08:11: 127.0.0.1 (1) has connected.
```

Comment: Acho que entendi.. mas se nao consigo acessar as informações que sejam do usuário nao é útil.. Preciso de uma soluçao alternativa acho.. as "gambiarras"

Comment: eu me perdi um pouco na explicaçao acho centralizei a resposta toda no seu último paragrafo, o método do apache vai a funcionar?

Comment: aparentemente funcionou aqui.. só uma dúvida, tem como obter os dados dessa variavel do usuario que se conecta? Pois testando em navegadores diferentes observei que ele resulta sempre os mesmo valores (que sao o do pc que iniciou o servidor)

Comment: Quando o usuário conecta eu envio esta mensagem para ele `md5($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` como disse ele retorna igual em todas as conexoes, o idel era que esses dados fossem do usuário conectando.. Obg =]

Comment: se voce me der uma referencia ou algo do tipo eu posso começar a pesquisar..

Comment: @user3163662 só conheço esta http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.socket-connect.php :(

Comment: to que procuro mas nao existe nada que fale que é possivel passar informacoes do usuario além do IP D:

Comment: @user3163662 Descobri lendo o link que te mandei, eu estava totalmente enganado, editei a resposta, espero que eu possa me redimir assim :) Até mais.

Comment: voce é um genio hehehe, muito obrigado <33