# Não deixar conectados se reconectarem, PHP

Tags: php, websocket

Estou a trabalhar em um servidor **WebSockets** que administra conexões entretanto não consigo resolver este pequeno impasse, não por falta de entendimento do código mas sim por não saber como fazer..

Vejam só,

1. O usuário se conecta ao servidor
2. Quando outro usuário se conectar ao servidor ***(ou seja no mínimo dois estão conectados)*** eles irão se conectar trocando informações através do servidor.
3. Quando o terceiro se conectar o mesmo processo tem que ser feito, mas os dois primeiros não precisam se re-conectarem entre sí novamente, eles precisam apenas se conectarem com o 3 e vice-versa.. para todos estarem conectados..

e assim por diante.. até no máximo 20 conexões.

No meu servidor atual ele apenas recebe a mensagem e repassa a todos conectados menos ao que está a enviar a mensagem, e isso faz com que o terceiro se conecte com o primeiro mas não com o segundo ai vira uma confusão...

Vale ressaltar que o servidor apenas repassa as mensagens, quem as trata e fazem a conexão de fato é o usuário no Browser.. O servidor apenas é a torre de sinal

como fazer isto essa administração em PHP ou pelo menos a lógica pra eu tentar fazer sozinha..

Comment: É um websocket ou é uma requisição (ajax por exemplo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quando o terceiro se conectar o mesmo processo tem que ser feito, mas os dois primeiros não precisam se re-conectarem entre sí novamente, eles precisam apenas se conectarem com o 3 e vice-versa.. para todos estarem conectados..

Até aonde entendo o websocket não conecta um a um dos usuários e sim e todos se conectam ao socket e por isto não precisa conectar 1 com 2 e 2 com 3 e 3 com 1 (foi o que eu entendi da sua lógica), então acredito que o problema seja com teu script.

Em outras palavras, todos recebem os mesmos dados, para isolar os dados é que seria mais complicado.

Sendo websocket, você terá que usar um sistema de cookies de sessão (talvez criado por você) para impedir que o usuário conecte novamente, ou então usar um esquema de IP (note que mais de um computador em uma rede compartilha um IP do ISP, então usar IPs é uma péssima pratica).

### Verificar se o usuário já está online

Me baseando nestas resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60061/3635

Para trazer o os dados do usuário como o "header cookie" (ou token) será necessário usar [`socket_recvfrom`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php)

### Verificar quantidade de conexões

Para impedir mais de 20 conexões, use o `socket_accept` adicionando a um vetor, algo como:

```
$accepts = array();

//Pedaço de código...

$accepts[] = socket_accept(...);


//Crie um método que verifica cookies e remove/elimina conexões sem sessão ou com sessão invalida e repetidas

if (count($accepts) > 20) {
   //Se a nova conexão for maior que 20 envia uma resposta que bloqueie o uso do chat no front-end
}
```

Algo que pode usar para começar o seu projeto é o https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

Do meu ponto de vista está um pouco desatualizado, mas é apenas para estudo.